# Почему i в цикле для корректной работы программы должна равняться 1, а не 0?

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написать программу, которая:
1. считывает с консоли число N, которое должно быть больше 0
2. потом считывает N чисел с консоли
3. выводит на экран максимальное из введенных N чисел.

```
    Требования:
    1. Программа должна считывать числа с клавиатуры.
    2. Программа должна выводить число на экран.
    3. В классе должен быть метод public static void main.
    4. Нельзя добавлять новые методы в класс Solution.
    5. Программа должна выводить на экран максимальное из введенных N чисел.
    6. Программа не должна ничего выводить на экран, если N меньше либо равно 0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что первое число (из `N` чисел) считывается *до* цикла.